# SQL Server - When to use Clustered vs non-Clustered Index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index, query-tuning

I know primary differences between clustered and non clustered indexes and have an understanding of how they actually work. I understand how clustered and non-clustered indexes improve read performance. But one thing I am not sure is that what would be the reasons where I would choose one over the other.

For example: If a table does not have a clustered index, should one create a non-clustered index and whats the benefit of doing

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am already aware of that. My question is would there be a situation where creating a non-clustered index would benefit more than creating a clustered index

Comment: Yes, you should avoid a clustered index when; the column has low cardinality, no particular order, frequently updated, non-sequential, it is a composite of many columns...

Comment: Perhaps this question would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070529/difference-between-clustered-and-nonclustered-index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What column should the clustered index be put on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440074/what-column-should-the-clustered-index-be-put-on)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I just want to put in a word of warning: please **very carefully** pick your clustered index! Every "regular" data table ought to have a clustered index, since having a clustered index does indeed speed up a lot of operations - yes, **speed up**, even inserts and deletes! But only if you pick a **good** clustered index.

It's the **most replicated** data structure in your SQL Server database. The clustering key will be part of each and every non-clustered index on your table, too.

You should use extreme care when picking a clustering key - it should be:

- **narrow** (4 bytes ideal)
- **unique** (it's the "row pointer" after all. If you don't make it unique SQL Server will do it for you in the background, costing you a couple of bytes for each entry times the number of rows and the number of nonclustered indices you have - this can be very costly!)
- **static** (never change - if possible)
- ideally **ever-increasing** so you won't end up with horrible index fragmentation (a GUID is the total opposite of a good clustering key - for that particular reason)
- it should be non-nullable and ideally also fixed width - a `varchar(250)` makes a very poor clustering key

Anything else should really be second and third level of importance behind these points ....

See some of Kimberly Tripp's (*The Queen of Indexing*) blog posts on the topic - anything she has written in her blog is absolutely invaluable - read it, digest it - live by it!

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Comment: Thanks marc_s for the clear explanation. But technically speaking, what does `non clustered` index do for us. what are its importance.. ?

Comment: @nad: a well chosen non-clustered index can speed up your searches - instead of having to compare potentially millions of rows of data with your search criteria, you can find a given row with just 4, 5 comparisons. That makes a ***HUGE*** difference!

Comment: @MuriloKunze: read [Kim Tripp's blog post on the topic](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) - she explains in great detail why this is the case

Comment: I am sorry, but where is the answer to the question "SQL Server - When to use Clustered vs non-Clustered Index?" ?