# Newsequentialid() as an Index Column?

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I have a `newsequentialid()` as a GUID Column and I wanted to know if I should index the column as Clustered or Non-Clustered Index as I will be using the GUID to query on.

I will also be inserting data into the table every week.

Comment: If you don't already have a clustered index then might as well use it up.

Comment: The answer given has lots of good info.
I certainly also like to ask people if they're very sure they need a GUID...  are you sure? :)   They have a place, but it is uncommon.  If you don't need an identifier unique around the planet, you might not need a GUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes put a clustered index on your table. But which columns to use as your clustered index? [Please see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304376/sql-server-when-to-use-clustered-vs-non-clustered-index/18306484#18306484). Should point you in the right direction. Especially the link to [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/). Much depends on the nature of your GUID. To paraphrase Kimberley Tripp's article: a GUID that is not sequential can be a bad choice. Examples:

- Generated in the client (using .NET)
- Generated by the newid() function

As there is quite a bit more to this decision than just that, I recommend you read the full answer provided by @marc_s and that entire article by Kimberley Tripp.

As far as the weekly data insert via SSIS consider these steps:

- Drop your target table's indexes prior to the insert
- Load your target table with a Data Flow
- Configure your OLE DB Destination with "Data access mode:" = "Table or view - fast load"
- Rebuild your target table's indexes after the insert

Depending on your specific situation what this can achieve is a dramatically faster insert and leave you with a clean index whose statistics are up to date and fragmentation is zero or near zero.

I realize your question states you are using `newsequentialid()`. [While I was reading this article on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) the actual sequential nature of the values produced by this function comes with a caveat: After restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but is still globally unique. Would this impact your downstream usage of the GUID?

I guess I am wondering why you find it necessary to use a GUID and why that is a better choice in your situation as opposed to an integer based SEQUENCE which would make your primary key clustered index significantly smaller.