# How to choose an index in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

How to choose an index for the SQL Server table?

```
R (ID, name, salary, zipcode)
```

`ID` is the primary key (clustered index)

Queries:

```
select * 
from R 
where salary < 4000 and name = "john"

select * 
from R 
where id = 100 and zipcode = '76200'

select * 
from R 
where salary > 10000
```

I have an exam tomorrow and since it is paper pen exam I cannot check whether the indices I chose are correct or not. So I am stuck in this question.

We need to choose 2 other indices and mention

1. which attribute form a search key
2. index should be clustered or unclustered
3. index should be hashed or B+ tree.

Could you please guide me on how to choose the index manually and justify the question above?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a good reading about that matter that can help you to choose the index manually
[SQL Server Index Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide)

and this SO link talk about clustering key, some point also mentioned in the above link
[picking a clustering key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304376)

Comment: Thank you. So it is like everyone has their own perception in choosing the index right ? I might choose Salary as clustered index (B+ tree) as it involves ranges and Zipcode as unclustered index as we cannot have range for it, it can be in Hash tree. Please correct me if I am wrong in this approach ?

Comment: @SrihariRaghu from what i know,  B-tree excels for range based searches and hash index better for strict equality. but AFAIK, sql server can only have 1 clustered index (and you already have that in your PK) so i'm not sure if you can have another clustered index

Comment: I think we can have more than one clustered indices. say if i take age (say) as clustered indices.

Comment: You can't have more than one clustered index, but you can select more than one column or else you can create multiple non-clustered index